# Logitech USB Unifying Receiver and USB-C Hubs

Tags: usb-c, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have a Logitech Unifying receiver with a Mouse and Keyboard connected to it.

In my setup, I have a two laptops that both connect over USB-C to a Hub with a HDMI Port and 2 USB 3.0 Type A Ports.

My goal is to have the USB-C hub connected to a Monitor via HDMI and my Unifying Receiver connected to the Hub, so I can trivially move the USB-C connection between laptops to use the monitor/keyboard/mouse.

This works fine for the HDMI, but the Unifying receiver doesn't switch. When connected to Laptop A, everything works. Then I switch the cable to Laptop B, the HDMI moves over, but the Logitech receiver does is not detected on Laptop B. The receiver works on both laptops if it's directly connected, and rebooting Laptop B with the hub connected will allow it to work.

I've now tried this with 2 USB-C Hubs, and 1 USB-C Dock and see the same behavior on all. Other devices (e.g. a USB headset) can move between the laptops on the hub, so I'm pretty sure it's not the Hub itself. It seems very specific to the unifying receiver connected to the hub.

I'd appreciate any advice on where the issue might be occurring and how I can resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the receiver is only enumerated at boot. You'd probably need Logitech to fix that. Try un- & re-plugging the receiver itself after you swap. Just tested with one on a Mac & that re-discovers it.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't help. After swap, I can move the receiver to the physical laptop and it will work. Move it back to the hub and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...this problem mysteriously disappeared without explanation when I moved my setup to another room in the house (May 2021, about a month after I posted the question). I've been using the receiver on the USB C hub between two laptops for almost two years, and the receiver worked as I moved it between devices. I haven't really thought about it anymore after that.

I recently bought a new desk and had to move all my equipment to swap the desk out. After I reconnected all my equipment back - boom. Back to the exact same problem from 2021. Keyboard and mouse would no longer work after plugging the hub into the other computer.

I carefully disconnected and reconnected everything. Tried power cycling. Different USB ports - nothing.

Then I did something silly. USB-C ports are supposed to be reversable right? I unplugged the hub, flipped the orientation, and plugged it back in.

Suddently, the reciever works fine again, regardless of which laptop I have it plugged into, via the hub. I must have reversed the connection when I moved it between rooms and it "mysteriously" started working.

Anyway, I'm not sure exactly why reversing the connection would make a difference, but it seems critical to me that it's plugged in a certain orientation.

In fact - I even noticed a warning on the USB-C extension cable I have which warns of this very thing:

[image: USB Warning]

If anyone else sees the same issue, I'd say it's at least worth a try.

Comment: Flipping the USB-C cable has worked for me too. After trying every imaginable fix, this is what worked. Thank you so much.

However, I have no idea why flipping the USB-C cable would work. Does anyone have a guess?

Edit: And now, if I flip the USB-C back again, it continues to work! So weird...

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd offer this solution for newer (post-2020) versions of macOS, although it applies to all scenarios and not just when using a USB hub.

It didn't work for me until I enabled `Input Monitoring` for the Logitech Unifying Software.

Open System Settings and go to "Privacy & Security" (or type "input monitoring" in the settings search bar.

[image: macOS-System-Settings-Input-Monitoring]

Then just enable "Input Monitoring" for the Logitech software by toggling the  switch button "on"

[image: Enable input monitoring for Logitech Unifying Software in macOS]

Once enabled, just restart the Logitech software and it should detect the USB receiver now.